# Size of background changes when I add border-image

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a forum name, height limit is 20px so both the border-image and background image are 20 px, but if I add a border-image, it basically doubles the size of the background for some reason

my code so far is -

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.cookie {
  color: #f4643d;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  background: url(backgroud.gif) bottom right repeat;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  text-shadow: 1px 0px 1px black;
  border-image: url(cookie.gif) 0% 100%;
  border-image-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<span class = "cookie">&nbsp&nbspCookie&nbsp&nbsp</span>
```

Comment: Do you need text in that element ???

Comment: Are you doing a CSS reset on your padding or no?